# Show that $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty }\frac {1} {\sqrt {n}}=0$

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty }\frac {1} {\sqrt {n}}=0$.

*Proof.* Let $\varepsilon >0$. We need to find $N$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$

$\left| \dfrac {1} {\sqrt {n}}-0\right| =\dfrac {1} {\sqrt {n}} < \varepsilon$.

*Claim*. By the Bernoulli inequality, $\left( 1+\left( n-1\right) \right) ^{1 / 2}\geq \dfrac {n-1} {2}+1=\dfrac {n+1} {2}$

So, $\dfrac {1} {\sqrt {n}}\leq \dfrac {2} {n+1}$ (by the Bernoulli's inequality)

$< \dfrac {2} {n}$.

Thus, $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty }\dfrac {2} {n}=2\lim_\limits{n\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac {1} {n}=2\times 0=0$.

**Can you check my proof?**

Comment: Your argument is one-half of an argument using the "squeeze" theorem rather than an $\epsilon, N$ proof.

Comment: For exponents $< 1$, the sense of the inequality in Bernoulli's inequality goes the other way. $(1 + x)^{1/2} \leqslant 1 + \frac{1}{2}x$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah, yes, right.

Comment: "We need to find N in N such that for all n≥N"  Apparently you don't need to do that because you didn't. So why state that you "need" to do that, when you don't? Your proof seems okay if:you prove that $\lim_{n-> \infty} \frac 1n = 0$ which I don't see you did anywhere.  and: you prove that if lim a_n = c then lim ba_n = bc which you also didnt prove. If we *assume* these things then we can *assume* lim $\sqrt{1/n} = \sqrt{\lim 1/n}$ ans sqrt is continuous. If we can't assume these things, then you need to follow your own advise "We need to find N in N such that for all n≥N" which is **EASY**.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\epsilon>0$ given. we want 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}<\epsilon$$

or  $$n>\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}$$

for $n>N$.

so, we can take

$$N=\lfloor \frac{1}{\epsilon^2} \rfloor +1$$

Comment: We didn't define greatest integer function in the class.

Comment: @Kahler And so what?

Comment: @Kahler you could use the fact that R is archimedian.

Comment: @Did not required

Comment: "We didn't define greatest integer function in the class."  Geez... use a *little* bit of incentive.  Select $N \ge \frac 1{\epsilon^2} + 1$.    That your class doesn't use that notation hardly warrants a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon>0$. Then $\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon^2$ for some $N \in \mathbb N$, by the archimedean property. But then $\frac{1}{\sqrt N}<\epsilon$, and since the sequence is decreasing, we see that the inequality holds as well for all $n>N$.